# Jmeter issue - SystemError","Message":"Validation failed for one or more entities

Tags: jmeter

I am new to this forum and have an issue currently which I am struggling with

When I try to post a request I get the following response:

> [{"Code":"SystemError","Message":"Validation failed for one or more
>   entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."}]

I am not sure what this means or where to start looking to fix it.
If I do the same request in postman it works so it's a bit baffling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing a proper [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) in your request. I would recommend adding [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, inspect request details being sent by JMeter and amend JMeter configuration to exactly match the request Postman sends.

Also you can simply **record** the Postman request by JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest and the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Template -> Recording -> Create`
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Configure Postman for recording. In order to set it to use JMeter as a proxy run it like:

   ```
   postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888
   ```

   See [Supported Chrome Command Line Switches](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md#--proxy-serveraddressport) for more details.
3. Run your request in Postman - JMeter should capture it under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller).